# How to get data from nested collection in angular firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I’m trying to fetch data from nested collection in angular firestore.
However, it gives me empty array always whatever it has data.
I read some articles that angular firestore doesn’t have that function.
Then what should I do to get data from nested collection.
I’d like to get all of documents from nested collection.

Comment: refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for getting nested collection,

Comment: if you can share error or code what are you trying to do, than it will be easier to get what help you need

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create proper rules for your nested collection, because nested collection works exactly like the root collection